# Experimental decorators warning in TypeScript compilation

Tags: typescript, decorator, visual-studio-code

I receive the warning...

> Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option `to remove this warning.

... even though my compilerOptions in tsconfig.json have the following settings:

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

What is weird is that some random classes that use decorators do not show that warning but the rest in the same project do.

What could cause such behavior in the TypeScript compiler?

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS Code? I've found that's necessary after making tsconfig.json changes sometimes.

Comment: Yes - I did it a few times - only difference is that different file is not having warning but others still

Comment: By chance if someone else runs into this that is using VS Professional, not VS Code, you may have added a `.ts` file to an angular project manually; if so, the default TS compilation is conflicting with Angular CLI.  Right-click the file -> Properties -> Build Action : None.  Then restart VS if needed.

Comment: VS Code restart helped me solve the issue.

Comment: @CMA Restarting VS code helped me too in this case.

Comment: @pbarranis  I hope your comment is an actual Answer somewhere.  After two hours of hunting, your comment was the solution for me.  I didn't know that every .ts file has its own "Build Action" property.  Thank you.

Comment: As @paulsm4 said, the problem showed up in my case after starting VSCode in the wrong directory.  You want to start VSCode in the directory where `tsconfig.json` is for your project.

Comment: Closing project and re-open the project solved my problem.

Comment: I encountered the warning too and restarting VS Code didn't help for me. I happen to remove the warning when I appended a ".component.spec.ts" to the file name.. so the spec file in my project "mycomponent.spec.ts" renamed into "mycomponent.component.spec.ts"

Comment: If using neovim then the same as the top comment, you need to restart item2 or whatever you are using for a terminal

Comment: In my case I got a hint from @pbarranis answer (although in VS code). My error was due to an empty (commented out) tsconfig.json in my module where the errors occurred  > solution was to remove that file (probably works to add the "experimentalDecorators": true, in that file, but the setting was already enabled in the main app tsconfig thus removing an unused file seemed better :)

Answer (score 455, accepted):

Although VS Code is a great editor for TypeScript projects, it needs a kick every now and again. Often, without warning, certain files cause it to freak out and complain. Mostly the fix seems to be to save and close all open files, then open `tsconfig.json`. After that you should be able to re-open the offending file without error. If it doesn't work, lather, rinse, and repeat.

If your `tsconfig.json` specifies its source files using the `files` array, IntelliSense will only function correctly if the file in question is referenced such that VS Code can find it by traversing the input file tree.

Edit: The 'reload window' command (added ages ago now) should solve this problem once and for all.

Comment: The answer was not really relevant to my case but somehow helped my figure out my problem.
I am using VS 2015 and between changing the `xproj` and `tsconfig` file, I missed the fact that the folder with my script files was listed in the `exclude` section of `tsconfig`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: File > Close folder > Open folder worked for me. This happened after I restarted the machine without properly closing vscode.

Comment: What if i am not using typescript? Only javascript es6?

Comment: Works with the Atom editor. All I had to do was to apply the lather-rinse cycle once; sigh...

Comment: I'm not sure when it was added but the command palette now has "Reload Window", which is ideal for this sort of thing.

Comment: Opening individual files or folders that doesn't include the tsconfig.json will cause this issue. If you open a folder inside your app rather than open the whole app folder, which would contain the tsconfig.json

Comment: used `include` instead of `files` and disappeared

Comment: I was getting the error in Visual Studio 2017.  I removed the warning by adding the following line to my tsconfig.spec.json file:

    "experimentalDecorators": true,

Comment: Use case: Copied my repo to another repo. Problem: My tsconfig file was now in a subdirectory and not anymore in the root. Fix: Make new one in the root or close folder and open the repo you going to work in so your tsconfig is in the root again!

Comment: I had this error a few minutes ago (Angular 8/VScode1.39) what worked for me is to go up a layer. I have the tendency of opening my projects directly from the `app/` directory. If you do that vscode won't always find `tslint.json` and freak out. Just opening the same project from the top level directory fixed it for me

Comment: thanks for the help!
closing all files, then opening tsconfig,json, >reload window, then opening the file concerned fixed it

Comment: 1. Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings.
2. Search "experimentalDecorators"
3. Check Enable/disable experimentalDecorators
4. Press Ctrl + S to save settings.

Comment: 'reload window' solved for me! Thank you! Use ctrl+shift + P and reload window

Comment: In my case I hadn't `cd`'d into the right directory before running `code .` to open VS Code.

Answer (score 511):

I've to add the following in the settings.json file of vscode to remove the warning.

```json
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true
```

VSCode -> Preferences -> Settings

[image]

**UPDATE**

As Clepsyd pointed out, this setting had been deprecated. You need to use now

```json
"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators":true
```

[image]

Comment: `ctrl + ,` shortcut key to open usersettings. on usersettings click 3 dots (`...`) then on pop up click `Open settings.json` to open `settings.json`

Comment: I needed to do this. The tsconfig.json solution worked fine until I added a new service, but this time deeper as usual in the directory tree. (app->component->xyz_comp->sub_component->sub_service)

Comment: This settings has been deprecated. You should now use: `"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true`

Comment: "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true .. fixed my issue.
Looks like the other approach is depricated.

Answer (score 210):

File -> Preferences -> Settings
[image]

Comment: For me, the issue appeared on version 1.37 and your solution solved it.

Comment: 1. Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings.
2. Search "experimentalDecorators"
3. Check Enable/disable experimentalDecorators
4. Press Ctrl + S to save settings.

Answer (score 122):

**Please follow the below step to remove this warning message.**

[image]

Step 1:
Go to setting in your IDE then find or search the **experimentalDecorators**.

[image]

Step 2: then click on checkbox and warning has been remove in your page.

[image]

Answer (score 117):

This error also occurs when you choose "src" folder for your workspace folder.

When the root folder, folder where the "src", "node_modules" are located is chosen, the error disappears

Comment: In case the above was not comprehensible: Vscode must load the folder where the config file is to know about it. If you want to load a folde further down I *guess* you could write a new config file that would be valid from that folder and below.

Answer (score 57):

inside your project create file tsconfig.json , then add this lines

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

In VSCode, Go to File => Preferences => Settings (or Control+comma) and it will open the User Settings file. Search "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true 
and then check the checkbox for experimentalDecorators to the file and it should fix it. It did for me.

[image]

Answer (score 29):

have to add `typescript.tsdk` to my `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me, but that line goes into `.vscode/settings.json` as per [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Nightly%20Builds.md#visual-studio-code)

Comment: Also solved it for me, but I didn't have the `.vscode` folder (I don't know why - I'm a backend dev, leave me alone!), so I created one in the root folder with said `settings.json` file.

Comment: Thank you!! How on earth did you figure this out?

Comment: Ahem! Ahem! Sometimes, the path to `node_modules` could not be resolved. If that is the case we need to give the full relative path to the same like `"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"`

Answer (score 27):

I get this warning displayed in vscode when creating a new Angular service with the

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

syntax (rather than providing the service in app.module.ts).

The warning persists until I reference the new service somewhere in the project.  Once the service gets used the warning goes away.  No typescript configuration or vscode settings changes necessary.

Comment: I my case it was solved also when I reference the new service somewhere in the proyect, thanks!

Answer (score 21):

For me, this error "Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. (etc)" only happened in VS Code in an Angular project and only when creating a new Service.

The solution above: "In Visual Code Studio Go to File >> Preferences >> Settings, Search "decorator" in search field and Checking the option JavaScript › Implicit Project Config: Experimental Decorators" solved the problem.

Also, stopping the ng serve in the terminal window and restarting it made the error disappear after recompile.

Answer (score 18):

In Visual Code Studio 
Go to File >> Preferences >> Settings, Search "decorator" in search field and Check the option as in image.
[image]

Answer (score 16):

This answer is intended for people who are using a **Javascript** project and not a **Typescript** one. Instead of a **tsconfig.json** file you may use a **jsconfig.json** file.

In the particular case of having the **decorators** warning you wan write inside the file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

Fort the buggy behaviors asked, it's always better to specify the "include" in the config file, and restart the editor. E.g.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "include": [
        "app/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just in case, in either language it's important that the files you are working with are inclided in the "include", for example "app/*/*.ts" or "app/*/*.js", etc. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 14):

Open `settings.json` file in the following location `<project_folder>/.vscode/settings.json`

or you can open the file from the menu as mentioned below

`VSCode -> File -> Preferences -> Workspace Settings`

[image: experimentalDecorators settings]

Then add the following lines in `settings.json` file

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
    "enable_typescript_language_service": false
}
```

That's all. You will see no warning/error regarding '**experimentalDecorators**'

Comment: I got "Unknown configuration setting" after adding "enable_typescript_language_service" using vscode 1.8.1

Comment: This is HORRIBLE advice if your project uses Typescript!

Comment: Disabling "enable_typescript_language_service" would effectively turn off any live linting TypeScript offers please avoid this suggestion.

Comment: This is worked for me. for more info refer below link also. 

https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-remove-experimentaldecorators-warning-in-vscode/

Answer (score 14):

```
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true
```

Will solve this problem.

Comment: @nadya: [`settings.json`](https://www.google.com/search?q=vscode+settings.json+location) (either user or workspace). You can also use the gui settings, as [this answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55611980/444255)

Answer (score 12):

Add following lines in tsconfig.json and restart VS Code.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**STEP 1:** Press  **ctrl + ,** in VS code

**STEP 2:** Enter *'js/ts.implicitProjectConfig: Experimental Decorators'* in search box

**STEP 3:** check the checkbox related to the search

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you are using cli to compile *.ts files, you can set experimentalDecorators using the following command:

```
 tsc filename.ts --experimentalDecorators "true"
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem recently under Visual Studio 2017 - turned out it was caused by a "feature" of VS - [ignoring tsconfig.json when Build action is not set to Content](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/208941/vs-156-ignores-tsconfigjson-and-typescriptcompileb.html).

So changing the Build action to Content and reloading the solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Not to belabor the point but be sure to add the following to

- Workspace Settings not User Settings

under File >> Preferences >> Settings

"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true

this fixed the issue for me, and i tried quite a few suggestions i found here and other places.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open VScode.
2. Press ctrl+comma
3. Follow the directions in the [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oUZn.png)

   1. Search about
      experimentalDecorators
   2. Edit it

Answer (score 6):

I had this error  with following statement

**Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your tsconfig or jsconfig to remove this warning.ts(1219)**

*It was there because* my Component was not registered in **AppModule** or (app.module.ts)
i simply gave the namespace like

**import { abcComponent } from '../app/abc/abc.component';**

and also registered it in **declarations**

Comment: I get the exact same error after creating a new file with "@Injectable() export class MyService {}" in it. Nothing to add to AppModule (ng10)

Comment: i had the same issue

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of clarity and stupidity.

1) Open .vscode/settings.json.

2) Add "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib" on it.

3) Save it.

4) Restart Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working in Visual studio. You can try this fix

1. Unload your project from visual studio
2. Go to your project home directory and Open "csproj" file.
3. Add TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators to this section as shown in image

   [image]

   4. Reload the project in Visual studio.

see more details at [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3934) location.

Comment: Did you really use a screen shot of the text?

Comment: yes, its screen shot from working project

Comment: Although I kindly want to downvote because of the screenshot, it gave me the solution as I don't use VS Code but VS 2022 and it was driving me nuts that tsconfig was fine and VS was still complaining about it.
This one is nonsense from ms: "_If you have a project file, tsconfig will not be honored. the project file takes precedence._" [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3934#issuecomment-123010291)

Answer (score 4):

Please check you oppened in your VS Code the folder of the entire project and not only the src folder, because if you open only the src, then ts.config.json (located in the project folder) file will not be in scope, and VS will not recognize the experimental decorators parameters.

In my case this fixed all the problems related to this issue.

Comment: This was also my issue. Can you see node_modules? Can you see tsconfig.json? If not, open a new vsCode window, close the old window, choose file-->open folder, and make sure you select the parent folder of `src` and `node_modules`, rather than selecting just `src`.

Answer (score 4):

in my case I solved this issue by setting `"include": [ "src/**/*"]` in my `tsconfig.json` file and restarting vscode.
I've got this solution from a github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9335

Answer (score 4):

I used React and Nest for my project.
Had this error displayed in the backend, but adding those two lines to react's tsconfig.json fixed the issue for some reason. Furthermore, everything above did not work for me

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Open entire project's folder instead of project-name/src

> tsconfig.json is out of src folder

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue while creating an **Injectable** Services in Angular 2.
I have all the things at place in tsconfig.json .Still I was getting this error at ColorsImmutable line.

```
@Injectable()
export class ColorsImmutable {
```

> And fix was to register the Service at module Level or Component Level
>   using the providers array.
>
> ```
> providers:[ColorsImmutable ],
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If you using Deno JavaScript and TypeScript runtime and you enable experimentalDecorators:true in tsconfig.json or the VSCode ide settings. It will not work. According to Deno requirement, you need to provide tsconfig as a flag when running a Deno file. See [Custom TypeScript Compiler Options](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/typescript)

In my particular case I was running a Deno test and used.

```
$ deno test -c tsconfig.json
```

If it is a file, you have something like

```
 $ deno run -c tsconfig.json mod.ts
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm already doing this and yet no luck, as they state in the docs experimental features will not work,

Comment: It will work. See updated answer of exactly the content of my tsconfig.json. Then see this link https://github.com/manyuanrong/dso/issues/18

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the same issue in the VS Code ***Version:1.76.0*** and fixed it by following these steps.

- Open any TS file > click on the *TypeScript* at the bottom line *Select language mode* [image]
- Then click on *Configure 'TypeScript' language based settings...*
- it will open the *settings.json* file [image]
- add line number 3 if it is not there. and save it:

```js
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
    "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators":true, // Add this line
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run with this code

```
 tsc .\src\index.ts --experimentalDecorators "true" --emitDecoratorMetadata "true"
```

Comment: this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This error can also mean that you have an error in tsconfig.json
In my case I was moving around a library and didnt fix path

```
"extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
```

After fixing it, error went away imidiately, no need to restart VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected the warning by removing "baseUrl": "", from the tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 1):

You might run into this issue if you open a TS file that exists outside of the project. For instance, I'm using lerna and had a file open from another package. Although that other package had it's own tsconfig with experimental decorators, VsCode doesn't honor it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues. It was fixed by importing the class with 'decorator warning' by other class.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just needed to import the component or module I created into another module(for example the shared module). Somehow this way VS Code realizes the file exists.

Comment: restarting vscode is best solution for this question in some scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I added this option to tsconfig.json, `"baseUrl": "front-end"` Replace front-end with the name of your angular-cli project.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with `ng build`. I've just rebuilt the app and now it's not complying.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out you can get around this by matching your module name to the file name. If you have the module name BankSpecialtyModule then the file name should be. bank-specialty.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error when I created a new module and move my *.module.ts and *-routing.module.ts file to another folder. After I deleted the two files and created the module on the new folder it works perfectly.
     Environment Angular Version 9 and Angular CLI version 9.1.0