# Visual Studio Code 'experimentalDecorators' Issue for Angular Build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am having an issue with VSC where all my typescript classes are triggering the intellisense and coming up with this warning:

> "[ts] Experimental support for is a feature that is subject to change
>   in a future build. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove
>   this warning."

This is a documented issue, with various fixes documented in these posts:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9335
- [Experimental decorators warning in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271273/experimental-decorators-warning-in-visual-studio-code)

However I am using a now more recent version of VSC (it was actually me updating it today that seems to have triggered something), and with that none of the solutions mentioned here seem to work.

I have:

- Added the "typescript.tsdk": "../node_modules/typescript/lib" option to my .vscode settings
- Removed various lines in the tsconfig.json file in the root of the app including lib, baseUrl and others, fully reopening VSC inbetween tries
- Tried alternate Typescript versions in my package.json
- Restarted my computer on the off chance

Here's my current tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using VSC version 2.3.2 and my TS version in my package.json is set to "typescript": "~2.2.0".

Is there something here I'm missing?

Comment: That version mismatch should not cause this error but you should most certainly update to the latest typescript.

Comment: Since you are using `outDir` you should also use `rootDir` or exclude your `dist` directory

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've updated to the latest typescript version via npm, added a `rootDir` (with the value `src`) and also attempted removing the `outDir` with the `./dist/out-tsc` directory, none of these have worked. Is that what you meant when you said to exclude it?

Comment: @jmcgrory, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @vlio20 No but I recommend trying the other solutions I have linked as they worked for others. I'm waiting for another VSC update to see if that shakes things up. Until then I'm ignoring the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
this is what what worked for me:  
tsconfig.js (relevant part):
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    ...
  },
  "include": [
    "src/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

Here is the full file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/db/**/*.ts",
    "src/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

Basically I just added the include attribute instead of using the files attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked, would you be able to post your full tsconfig.js?

Comment: thanks! Still no luck but it's not stopping me working so maybe I'll figure it out by the end of the year :D