# Allow experimental decorators visual studio

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic2

I get this error whenever I create new class

[image]

`Allow experimental decorators visual studio`

I'm using Ionic2 and was trying to implement local storage, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271273/experimental-decorators-warning-in-visual-studio-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271273/experimental-decorators-warning-in-visual-studio-code), nothing worked.

`"experimentalDecorators": true`