# vscode: [ts] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting "[ts] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning."

I'm new to Angular and I don't how to solve it.

My tsconfig.json file :

```
    {  
    "compilerOptions":{  
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
      "declaration":false,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata":true,
      "experimentalDecorators":true,
      "lib":[  
         "dom",
         "es2015"
      ],
      "module":"es2015",
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "sourceMap":true,
      "target":"es5"
    },
    "include":[  
       "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude":[  
       "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave":false,
    "atom":{  
       "rewriteTsconfig":false
     } 
   }
```

Print :

[image]

Comment: Which version pf TypeScript is VSCode  using? (See the bottom right corner in VSCode)

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48185725/5035048)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I already have the answer below, and it worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've opened the editor on the src folder. For vscode's language service to find your tsconfig, you need to open the editor on the true root of the project holding your config.

Opened on root folder: 
[image]

Opened on src folder: 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can set

```
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true
```

in your vscode setting.

Answer (score 2):

Move your **`tsconfig.json`** inside the root folder and restart the IDE. That should work.

Comment: It's already there.

I have a folder , the root, there are ionic.config.json,package.json and tsconfig.json and so on.


but the warning keeps showing

Comment: try this Go to File/preference/user settings in vscode, put this code

Comment: {
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}

Comment: I still have the same issue

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Moved it to ./src and it stopped giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Meirion Hughes answer is correct, I just want to add that this works in JS environments as well.

In that case name the config file `jsconfig.json`.