# TypeScript, Vue and experimentalDecorators

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I've created a Vue project through Vue-CLI v3.0.0-beta.15, now, everything is working, I mean, when I do `npm run serve` it compiles and runs fine but TypeScript throws the following error message and **only inside the editor!**

```
Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

**The things I've tried and didn't work:**

1. I double check that the `experimentalDecorators` is set to true in my `tsconfig.json` file which Vue does by default.
2. I tried to create a `jsconfig.json` file with the following options:

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "experimentalDecorators": true
       }
   }
   ```
3. I tried to change the following options in VSCode `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true`

Now, I'm using the Vetur extension with VSCode which I already posted an [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/815) on their repo **but I don't use any extensions with Visual Studio for Vue and yet I get the same error** so I don't know what triggers it but I think that something doesn't pick the `tsconfig.json` file.

**Here are the steps I've taken to generate the project:**

1. mkdir experiment && cd $_
2. npm init
3. npm install -D `@vue/cli`
4. ./node_modules/.bin/vue create dashboard
5. I've used the following options:

   - Check the features needed for your project: Babel, TS, PWA, Router, Vuex, CSS Pre-processors, Linter, Unit, E2E
   - Use class-style component syntax? Yes
   - Use Babel alongside TypeScript for auto-detected polyfills? Yes
   - Pick a CSS pre-processor (PostCSS, Autoprefixer and CSS Modules are supported by default): SCSS/SASS
   - Pick a linter / formatter config: TSLint
   - Pick additional lint features: Lint on save
   - Pick a unit testing solution: Mocha
   - Pick a E2E testing solution: Cypress
   - Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, PostCSS, ESLint, etc.? In dedicated config files
   - Save this as a preset for future projects? No
6. Then navigate to dashboard/src/views/Home.vue

That's how it looks like in **Visual Studio**:

[image]

And that's how it looks like in **VSCode**:

[image]

Comment: I'll just throw this one in from memory, but I had a similar error some weeks bakc, with an not updated version of vetur from code marketplace. To be more specific, check your `%UserProfile%\.vscode\extensions\vetur\vetur\package.json`, check the dev-dependencies (last in the file and compare to  https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/blob/master/package.json (tslint version I think)

Comment: Will try that soon. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I had to create `jsconfig.json` at the root of the folder where the `tsconfig.json` file is and the error in Visual Studio goes away but VSCode still displays the error regardless to the options I've set but this seems like it's a Vetur [bug](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/815) as opposed to a bug in VSCode, TypeScript or a configuration issue.

Opening the `Dashboard` folder as opposed to the `Src` folder which is the actual root of my project "fixed" the problem in VSCode so I guess that Vetur doesn't pick the `tsconfig.json` file when it's nested.

Comment: This worked for me too. To add to it, I left my original tsconfig.json where it was, and created another one in the root folder that contained only the single compilerOption for experimentalDecorators, with no paths, includes, excludes, or anything else. That seemed to work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I added jsconfig.json with the `experimentalDecorators` and left my tsconfig.json intouch. Visual Studio 2019 Community still show the errors.

Comment: @DucVuNguyen This seems to be unrelated to this issue, Vetur is the engine (extension) that provides the Vue experience in Visual Studio **Code** and this issue relates to Vetur specifically, I'm not sure what doesn't work for you but you might to report it to the Visual Studio team directly within VS2019 using the report feature.

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen this [post](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45071) ?

Maybe you should try : 
Go to File => Preferences => Settings (or Control+comma) and it will open the User Settings file. Add "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true

**EDIT :**

Ok so in your first exemple you have opened your project in the `experiment` directory, but the tsconfig.json is located in a sub directory, the tsconfig must be in the root directory. try to open vscode with `dashboard` as the root folder of your vscode project and restart your editor.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work, I've edited my post with more details.

Comment: Can you show your project tree in your editor ? 
Maybe you've opened your editor on the src folder like in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580327/vscode-ts-experimental-support-for-decorators-is-a-feature-that-is-subject-to)

Comment: It's not the case but I can definitely post it, maybe, I'm missing something.

Comment: Mate, this is the root directory, however, I tried to move it to up to the `.experiment` directory and I still get the same error.

Comment: Moving the tsconfig.json file higher will break everything, this is definitely where it should be because the dashboard directory is literally everything the vue-cli generated and what the default template contains.

Comment: Ok the problem is that you have create a new project and installed `@vue/cli` as dev dependencies.
Vue-cli liked the in [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/) should be installed in the global dependencies and `vue create my-project` is a command that generates a entiere project named `my-project` wich has `my-project` as root folder (containing the tsconfig etc..). In your case `dashboard` must be your root folder because it's the project and vscode needs to have the tsconfig.json in the root folder to recognize it.
Do you understand what i mean ?

Comment: You should not move the tsconfig.json, you have to open the project with your editor in the right directory wich is `dashboard`

Comment: I understand what you mean but I disagree with you,you don't have to install the cli globally unless explicitly stated that you absolutely must to do it, the tsconfig.json file IS in the correct location and the root of the project is where you put the tsconfig.json file at least from TypeScript point of view.

Comment: Again. like I stated in my post everything work, when I do npm run serve or vue serve it compiles and runs fine.