# Missing tsconfig.json file and Experimental Decorators warning in vsCode

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, tsconfig

In `Angular 6.0.3` (`global Angular CLI v6.0.8`, `local Angular CLI v6.0.7`) I'm suddenly getting intellisense errors on every component that I open: *`Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.`*

I've tried the instructions from the accepted answer here: [Experimental decorators warning in TypeScript compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271273/experimental-decorators-warning-in-typescript-compilation)

But my tsconfig.json file already had `"experimentalDecorators": true`.

I've also tried closing and re-opening `visual studio code`, clicking the `refresh` button on the file tree, `Reload Window` command etc etc ad nauseum. 
I think my issue may lie in the fact that I can't see `tsconfig.json` anywhere in my file structure (so perhaps neither can Angular). I believe it does exist because I do see `tsconfig.app.json` and this file has a link to `tsconfig.json` which I can `ctrl + click` to follow to the `tsconfig.json` file.

**How can I find the location of `tsconfig.json` and/or make it appear at the same file level as `tsconfig.app.json` like the rest of my dev team has?**

My `tsconfig.app.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",  //I can ctrl + click here to go to tsconfig.json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

My (missing/invisible) `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you can follow the file with ctrl+click then probably the IDE decided not to display it. Can you confirm from the file system that the file indeed exists?

Comment: Did you try any of the other answers from the question you linked (not just the accepted)? You probably should start there.

Comment: @fridoo yes, I did. The others either weren't relevant to me or didn't work. I tried adding `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"` to settings.json to no avail. Actually, on relaunch vscode warned me that `node_modules/typescript/lib` was not a valid path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - got it. I realized I couldn't see the `node_modules` folder at the highest level of my file tree, nor `tsconfig.json`. I had accidentally directed vsCode to open only the src folder, rather than the parent folder of src and node_modules.

I opened a new vscode window, closed the old and made sure when I clicked file --> open folder, I pointed to the parent folder containing both src and node_modules. This is also the level where tsconfig.json exists, which is why I couldn't see it prior.

The intellisense errors went away, I assume because Angular can now actually see tsconfig.json (which already had "experimentalDecorators": true).