# Angular Error about experimentalDcorators

Tags: angular, typescript

I downloaded the project from Github.
I ran it on localhost and its showing following error>>
**"Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning."**

Anyone have any idea about it please help..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61341444/error-set-the-experimentaldecorators-option-in-your-tsconfig-or-jsconfig)

Answer (score 0):

In the root of the project you should ve an tsconfig.json file. You must enable experimentalDecorators :

```
...,
"compilerOptions": {
    ... ,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
}
```

Comment: It was already enabled in first place

Comment: So it must be something else that break the build. Because this is a warning and not an error. You can try to find more how to fix this warning here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271273/experimental-decorators-warning-in-typescript-compilation/38296690